# Convert IGrouping to IList<Class>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to take results from a IGrouping query and put it into a list.

I tried to do do this as follow:

The Entity class

```
public class WordRank
{

    public string Word { get; set; }
    public string WordScore { get; set; }
}
```

The method

```
     public void DisplayArticles()
    {
        var articles = this.articleRepository.TextMinerFindBy(this.view.Client, this.view.Brand, this.view.Project, this.view.Term, this.view.Channel, this.view.Begin, this.view.End, this.view.OnlyCategorized, this.view.UniquePosts);
        string snippets = string.Empty;

        foreach (var article in articles)
        {
            snippets = snippets + " " + article.Snippet;
        }

        Regex wordCountPattern = new Regex(@"[.,;:!?""\s-]");
        string snippetCollection = wordCountPattern.Replace(snippets, " ");

        var words = snippetCollection.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var groups = words.GroupBy(w => w);


        foreach (var item in groups)
        {
            this.view.Words.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

But is not possible to assign item to IList.
Can anybody give me light?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what your question is.

Comment: what do you gain in the `GroupBy` here? Why not just call `words.Distinct().ToList()` ?

Comment: I get the list of the words and the number of time they occur in the text, so I get this results to insert in IList<WordRank> Words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now that we know what you're trying to do (see comments):

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    this.view.Words.Add(new WordRank { Word = group.Key,
                                       WordScore = group.Count() });
}
```

Or if you're happy to replace the whole of `this.view.Words` with a `List<WordRank>`, replace the whole bottom bit with:

```
this.view.Words = words.GroupBy(w => w)
                       .Select(new WordRank { Word = group.Key,
                                              WordScore = group.Count() })
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! The type of this.view.Words is IList<WordRank> Words { get; set; }.  I've tried to implement your sugested solution but I still receive the message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Cultura.Extraction.Core.Entities.Articles.WordRank>'. Could you help me to convert this? Or something like that? Thanks again!

Comment: You need to give us the class definition of `Cultura.Extraction.Core.Entities.Articles.Word‌​Rank`

Comment: Sure, the class definition: namespace Cultura.Extraction.Core.Entities.Articles
{
    public class WordRank
    {

        public string Word { get; set; }
        public string WordScore { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: @user1867530: Well you've got several *groups* - it's not at all clear how you're expecting to convert a group of words into a WordRank.

Comment: Well, I dont need to convert a group into a Class WordRank, but if there is anyway I can display this group in a gridview, it will be usefull.

Comment: @user1867530: Then I don't understand what you're trying to do. You've got `groups` which is a sequence of groups. What do you want to do with them? If `Words` is an `IList<WordRank>` and you're currently trying to add each group to that list, how do you expect that to work? You haven't given us *nearly* enough context here.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I intent to get a group of words from a text. Then I count how many times each word occurs in the text and finally, I need to display this words in a gridview.

Comment: @user1867530: That doesn't answer my question. Each group is a sequence of strings. You're trying to add it to an `IList<WordRank>`. How do you want that conversion to happen? I'm not sure how many different ways I can ask that...

Comment: I would like to convert the values of group into the IList<WordRank> like: the property word would receive the words and the property wordscore would receive the number of times that word occurs as (word: someword, wordscore: 35)

Comment: @user1867530: Okay, finally. That's easy - editing the answer now. But *please* pay more attention to context next time. We shouldn't need to keep asking for this information.

Comment: Sorry Jon! At the begining of this problem I thought my problem was just simple convertion, but it become more complex than I thought. Next time will be sure to give the entire context. Sorry, and thanks for your patience.

Comment: @user1867530: Well it *is* simple conversion - it's just you didn't tell us what that conversion was meant to do. Anyway, hopefully the answer will sort you out now.

Comment: Pretty good Jon! Thanks for all your support! I can't beleve I've didn't saw that. Thnaks for your patience again!